How to control which inline element whitespace is associated with
In my statically generated site, I have a list of links with parenthetical explanations, with entries like

Here is a link (and some more explanation).

When I run a code formatter on the source HTML, it looks something like the first example in the code below: There is a line break at the end of the link text. Unfortunately, this causes the whitespace to be associated with the link text instead of the <span> element containing the parenthetical explanation.
As a result, the underline indicating the link extends over the space, which looks bad. In the second link, I fix this problem by modifying the source so that there is no line break before </a>, but this results in inconsistent code formatting and is easy to break if I forget to disable formatting in my IDE. Here is a screenshot from Firefox 130.0.1:

And here is the source:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="https://example.com">
        This link looks weird because the whitespace is associated with it
      </a>
      <span>
        (explanation)
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="https://example.com">
        This link looks as desired, but only because of how I formatted the
        source HTML</a>
      <span>
        (explanation)
      </span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

Is there a way to force the whitespace out of the </a> tag that is robust to HTML formatting, e.g. using CSS?

Edit: This post was flagged as a duplicate of Trim whitespace in link with css. However, the accepted answer to that question, which is to style the <a> element with display: inline-block, does not solve the problem, as it causes the browser to try to keep the lines of text in the link together, as in the following screenshot:

(The question is also from 2016, and CSS has expanded considerably since then.)
The other solutions suggested are to fiddle with the margin-right of the paragraph, which is hacky (it requires visually matching the margin to the size of a space in the font, which itself could vary depending on user settings), and to not format my code (which is the central purpose of the question).
I have also rolled back an edit that added a codepen around my code while breaking the indentation style.

You can solve this by not putting tags on their own lines. You should be writing tags on the same line as their content. This will solve the problem without needing to rely on special CSS or formatting to fix it.

While you are correct that the canonical posts' solutions are not satisfying –  the topic is the same hence a duplicate. In your case you could concider to start a bounty to draw more attention to this topic. Another hack could be to give the adjacent span an absolute position. This will introduce other isses like ugly overflows. See codepen. I'm afraid there is no perfect solution.

The other cannot have been the same question as mine, or else the OP wouldn't have marked a solution that doesn't solve my problem as the solution. Their failure to phrase the question more precisely isn't my fault.

Try this,


p {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px; /* adjust as pleased */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="https://example.com">
        This link looks weird because the whitespace is associated with it
      </a>
      <span>
        (explanation)
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="https://example.com">
        This link looks as desired, but only because of how I formatted the
        source HTML</a>
      <span>
        (explanation)
      </span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>




This answer could benefit from literally any explanation at all as to what it does and why it solves OP's problem.

HTML can be a bit finicky like that. This is the only solution I could find.


a {
  display: inline-block;
}
<p>
  <a href="stackoverflow.com">
    Run.
  </a>
  <span>(Explanation)</span>
</p>




Please don't spam, which includes posting links to websites you're affiliated with, for no reason other than to share the website.

I understand. I'm new to posting.
